# How to put a textbox text in my jQuery function in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var progress_key = '<?= $uuid ?>';

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pb3").progressBar({ max: 2000, textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );
    $(".pb4").progressBar({ max: 2000, textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );
    $(".pb5").progressBar({ max: 2000, textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );

    });
</script>
```

I am using a jQuery progress bar, and I want to dynamically generate the max field
with text from a text box control. Is this possible and what would I use?

```
maxValue3 = $(['[id*=label4']).val();
maxValue4 = $(['label5']).val();
maxValue5 = $(['id*=label6']).val();

$(".pb3").progressBar({ max: (maxValue3), textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );
$(".pb4").progressBar({ max: (maxValue4), textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );
$(".pb5").progressBar({ max: (maxValue5), textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { if (data.running_value == data.value) {  } }}  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the value on DOM load then you could do it like this.

```
$(function() {
 //establish a default value to fall back on
 var defaultValue = 2000, 
 //find the textbox using a wildcard ID check - since ASP.NET has tiered IDs
     maxValue = $(['[id*=your_asp_textbox_id']).val() || defaultValue;

 $(".pb3").progressBar({ max: (maxValue), textFormat: 'fraction', callback: function(data) { 
...

});
```

Comment: i tryed it multiple ways but i get NaN as my max

Comment: What the ID of the textbox?  Try using parseInt() on maxValue to make sure its not in a string format.

Comment: attributes should go inside square brackets [], so it would look like maxValue5 = $('[id*=label6]').val();

Comment: by that, i mean get rid of the square brackets outside of the quotes.

Comment: maxValue5 = $('#<%= label6.ClientID %>').html();